# Vue 2 - select set selected with boolean value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can I set selected option based on the boolean value.

**country.show** can be 0 or 1, and based on that, I want to have preselected option. This is the code snippet:

```
<td>
    <select name="show" class="form-control country-show">
        <option value="0" :selected="country.show == 0">No</option>
        <option value="1" :selected="country.show == 1">Yes</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically this is done with `v-model`. You could also use `:value="country.show"` assuming you just want to initialize it and use `v-model` for some other bind.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    country: {
      show: 0
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <h2>Using v-model</h2>
    <select name="show" v-model="country.show">
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
  </select>
  </div>



  <div>
    <h2>Using :value</h2>
    <select name="show" class="form-control country-show" :value="country.show">
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
    </select
  </div>
  
    <div>
    <h2>Using code from your question</h2>
    <select name="show" class="form-control country-show">
        <option value="0" :selected="country.show == 0">No</option>
        <option value="1" :selected="country.show == 1">Yes</option>
    </select
  </div>
</div>
```

FWIW, what you have works to pre-select a value, it's just not how you would normally do it in Vue.

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot of the help :)

Comment: 0 and 1 are numeric, not booleans. This answer is not accurate and does not answer the question stated by OP.

Answer (score 2):

The value property of option element is string in HTML. You can try this get selected option based on a boolean value

```
<td>
    <select name="show" class="form-control country-show" v-model="country.show">
        <option v-bind:value="false">No</option>
        <option v-bind:value="true">Yes</option>
    </select>
</td>
```